# Cannot get a proper return value using ADT in member fucntion

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, abstract-data-type

```
template<class Type>
Type* unorderedLinkedList<Type>:: newSearch(nodeType<Type> *head, const Type& x)const
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return 0;

    if (head->info == x)
        return ???(head or *head?);

    return newSearch(head->link, x);
}

template <class Type>
Type* unorderedLinkedList<Type>::recursiveLinkSeqSearch(const Type& item) const
{
    nodeType<Type> *current;
    current=this->first;
    return newSearch(current, item);


}
```

Now I feel stupid for asking this question but I cannot figure out the return value on this function.  In the main code I need to return a bool or something like it. The main looks something like.

```
unorderedLinkedList<classType> l1;
   classType *st;
   l1.recursiveLinkSeqSearch(st);
   if(l1){}else{};
```

I have done a lot of varitions on the functions with no success and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Seems should be return head. what error messages did you get?

Comment: The error is "cannot initialize return object of type 'dataType *' with an lvalue of type 'nodeType<classType>*

Comment: how about trying changing "Type* unorderedLinkedList<Type>:: newSearch(nodeType<Type> *head, const Type& x)const" to "Type* unorderedLinkedList<Type>:: newSearch(<Type> *head, const Type& x)const"?  just remove noteType.

Comment: Ill give it a shot and come back with the results

Comment: `return &head->info;` You want the data at the node, not the node.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you should return 'head'. If the types really have to stay the way they are, you'd have to do a type-cast:

```
return (Type*)head;
```

However, maybe what you want to do instead is change the return value of your functions:

```
template<class Type>
nodeType<Type>* unorderedLinkedList<Type>:: newSearch(nodeType<Type> *head, const Type& x)const
{
// Function body
}

template <class Type>
nodeType<Type>* unorderedLinkedList<Type>::recursiveLinkSeqSearch(const Type& item) const
{
// Function body
}
```

It's hard to tell for sure without knowing the details, though, so it's possible you want to do something else, too.

Comment: The type-cast caused a linker error, and this would work however the program is for school, and I cannot change the param on recursiveLinkSeqSearch.  The main thing is I need it to return a bool, or bool like value

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments above

```
return &head->info;
```

this fixed all the issues with the class and resolved the issue of the data type